# CUDA multiple threads work with one pointer

Tags: cuda

Well, for example I have some array `Y` and I want to increment `Y[0]` in multiple threads. 
If I only make `Y[0]++` in `__global__` function then `Y[0]` will be 1.
So, how to resolve this?

Comment: one approach would be to use [atomics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726299/how-does-warp-work-with-atomic-operation/20726558#20726558).  Another approach would be a [classical parallel reduction](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf).  This is a fairly basic concept, and so variants of this question have been asked many times here on the `cuda` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atomic operations are implementation dependent. If this compiles with no warnings, it is likely to work, but should be tested :-), or at least examine the assembler.

```c++
__global__ void mykernel(int *value){
    int my_old_val = atomicAdd(value, 1);
}
```

See the guide [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions)

Comment: OP asks for CUDA not C